# How can I cross my task as done without affecting the delete icon in my todo app

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a to-do app, it was going well until I tried adding the mark task as line-through on click if we want to check done task... now the thing is I also appended a span tag to the list tag carrying the task and this span task contains my delete icon. So when I click on the task, the line-through styling also affects my delete icon

```
listContainer.addEventListener( 
  "click", 
  function (delCheck) { 
    if (delCheck.target.tagName === "LI") { 
      delCheck.target.classList.toggle("checked"); 
    } else if (delCheck.target.tagName === "SPAN") { 
      delCheck.target.parentElement.remove(); 
    } 
  }, 
  false 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the `li` element so as to apply the strikethrough ends up applying the strike-through onto all other elements inside it.
The best approach is to select a specific element like the text or create a div that encloses the text and add an event listener to it. Like in the example image below where we just need to have the strike-through affecting only the lime colored container.

[image: Example implementation]

Example Code below.

```html
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>replit</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"/>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <ul>
        <li class="task-list-element">
          <div id="task-list-element-container">
            <p class="task-list-element-text">read something as interesting as this book</p>
          </div>
          <span id="btn-delete">
            <box-icon color="red" type="solid" name="folder-minus"> </box-icon>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```css
    html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .task-list-element{
      width: 450px;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 0 15px 0 0;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }
    #task-list-element-container{
      padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
      background-color: lime;
      cursor: pointer
    }

    #btn-delete{
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

JS

```js
    const textBox = document.getElementById("task-list-element-container");
    const btnDelete = document.getElementById("btn-delete")

    textBox.addEventListener("click", () => {
      textBox.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
      textBox.style.color ='red'
    });

    btnDelete.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const parentElement = btnDelete.parentElement;
      return parentElement.remove();
    })
```

You can interact with this [codepen](https://codepen.io/moreh-wa-chege/pen/ExrPwgM) as well